# Javascript: string regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am calling a function `getParentElm(idStr,element)` which accepts an id and an element, and searches up the html tree until it finds a parent element which has an id equal to `idStr.`

Calling code:

```
var s = "someId";  
var el = getParentElm(s,element);
```

I would like the `idStr` parameter to work with strings that match to `"someId"`, for eg `"someId123"`.
I tried :

```
var s = "/someId/";
```

but it did not work. Ideally, i do not want to touch the `getParentElm` function.

Update: Thanks vbranden.
I tried: var s = /someId/  and that worked. I upvoted your comment. Thanks all :)

Comment: should it match someId123? or should it work only for someId

Comment: the getParentElm function would need to do a regex match if you are supplying it with a regex. if it is only doing an === then you would need to modify the function to accept regex as well.

Comment: Agree. 
Check out W3C's tutorial on JS's regular expression @ http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp. I think S will have to be var s = /someId/ (without the double quotes)

Comment: Might be helpful if you can share with us the implementation of your getParentElem function.

Comment: var s = /someId/; or var s = new RegExp("someId");

Comment: We need to see the `getParentElm` function to be able to assist you

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should work :

```
function getParentElm(idStr,element) {
   var patt = new RegExp(idStr +".*");
   while(element.parentNode)
   {  
      if(patt.test(element.parentNode.id))
        return element.parentNode;
      element=element.parentNode;
   }
   return false;
}
```

And just call the function in this way :

```
var el = getParentElm("someId",document.getElementById('foo'));
```

Comment: where does this meet the requirement of constraining the acceptable ids to ones that start with "someId"? or address his question about regex?

Comment: .* will match all letters after

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn there would need to be a regex in the answer to use .*

Comment: @vbranden  you just have to pass "someId" as an argument. Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

no regex needed.

use `closest` to traverse up the dom, and `id*` to match id's which contains your `idStr`.

```
function getParentElm(idStr,element){
    return $(element).closest('[id*="' + idStr + '"]');
}
```